# Ubuntu file manager, web upload look

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I don't know how to make the title any better.

Using Ubuntu 18.04, Nautilus file explorer, when uploading a file to the internet, or Slack or Discord or whatever, the interface will look somewhat like this: [image]

The icons are too small. I'm looking for a way to turn them in to thumbnails, preferably with a small, medium, large setting.

Is this possible with Nautilus or do I need to switch to a different file explorer?

EDIT: Yes, the image linked in the comments looks nice. Customizable thumbnail size is what I'm looking for. So, y'know, I can actually preview what I'm uploading.

Comment: I think you're referring to the GTK file chooser dialog and not to Nautilus.

Comment: Anyway, is what you want something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGtpF.png?

Comment: @DKBose If I run `nautilus` from the terminal, I get that file explorer. Looks the exact same so I assume it's the exact same. And yeah something like that looks better.